# CSS display: inline-block does not accept margin-top?

Tags: css, position, label, margin

I have an element with display: inline-block, but it doesn't seem to accept margin-top. Is this because the element is still treated as an inline element?

If yes, does anyone have a workaround?

---

**EDIT #1**:

My CSS is quite simple:

```css
.label {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 7px 7px 5px;
}
```

I ended up wrapping the content in another div and giving that a margin-top. But that causes a lot of extra markup and makes my code less clear.

**EDIT #2**:

`margin-top` & `margin-bottom` on `inline-block` elements only seems to work with positive values.

Comment: sure it does, post the markup and css you're having trouble if you want our help

Comment: No and to help further we would need to see your code.  Here's a helpful link though http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: i have several layouts with inline-block elements positioned using margins, even margin-top

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I used `display: table`. It has the content-fitting properties of inline-block but also supports negative margins in a way that will shift the content following it up along with it. Probably not how you should be using it, but it works.

```
.label {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: table;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 7px 7px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Right or not, I don't know but it fixed my problem as well.

Comment: @baohouse Amazing!

Answer (score 100):

you can also try replacing the negative margin with

```css
.label{
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
}
```

in addition to the rest of your `.label` style

Comment: position: relative will move the element up by 2px relative to it's position, but it won't move the rest of the content below it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you can add `margin-bottom:-2px` to `.label` to balance it, and you don't have to add an extra div. but if you want to move everything from label down, wouldn't it be easier to set `margin-bottom:-2px` on whatever there is before .label?

Comment: Negative margin-top or bottom on inline-block elements doesn't work, as we discoverd earlier on. :)

Comment: Not a good solution. `position:relative;` always occupies space. You end up having unnecessary `2px` below.

Answer (score 21):

You can try `vertical-align` like this:

```css
.label {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -2px;
  vertical-align: 2px;
  padding: 7px 7px 5px;
}
```

I made an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmmbreeze/X6BjK/.
But vertical-align not work well on IE6/7. And there is a opera(11.64) rendering bug.

So I recommend to use `position:relative` instead.

Comment: Whats the reliability of using `vertical-align` in em(or %) in 2018?

Comment: @Hemant_Negi Should be fine as long you’re using something with a sane layout engine (IE ≥ 8 qualifies I think).

Answer (score 9):

That is indeed the case. Instead of a margin, you could use a padding. Another solution would be to use a container div for the element. You make that div `inline-block`, and make your current element a block inside that container. Then, you can give a margin to your element.

It would help if you got a concrete example, preferably in jsfiddle.net or so. It would help answers to be more specific too, instead of containing just general descriptions like mine here. ;)

Comment: It seems to work fine in chrome and IE8.  Is this a browser specific issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/PeNks/

Comment: I needed a negative margin, it does seem to work with positive margins. :(

Comment: lteIE7 only supports inline-block when it is applied to inline elements, it won't work with block elements such as <div>s.