# Negative margin is not working after setting display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I was intending to set the `p` tag next to my image and moving the top a bit.
The code as following:

```
    <style>
      * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      p {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-top: -20px;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <img src="myimg.png">
      <p>this is the intro of the page</p>
    </body>
```

I found no matter what value I set to the `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` of the `<p>` tag, it won't work as expected, is it something problem with calling `display:inline` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS display: inline-block does not accept margin-top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611030/css-display-inline-block-does-not-accept-margin-top)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a negative margin on an `inline` or `inline-block` element like that.  You could add a `position:relative;` and a negative top.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
p {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
<p>this is the intro of the page</p>
```

Also, I am assuming that you will change the CSS?  Going that global (by affecting all the elements with `*` and all the paragraphs with `p`) seems rather drastic.  Better to use classes and target what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer Jonathan, that's working for me!  just i have a question about is the top property is work same as margin-top here?

Comment: And personally i like to make * to reset all the margins and paddings in the start, i am wondering is this a good habit? I got this from a video

Comment: Awesome!  Not quite sure what you mean by "is work same", because (as you have seen) margin-top does not do anything with inline elements.  If, however, you mean does `top:0;` leave it where it is and `top:-10px;` move it up by 10px, then yes.

Comment: Regarding `*`, if you like working that way, it is fine!  Just realise that you will have to add margin beneath your paragraphs and headers for spacing, to indent your list-items, etc.  It's really a matter of preference though.  But putting a negative margin on all paragraphs is probably not a good idea, nor making them all inline elements; that is what spans are for.