# the clickable area of an anchor become bigger after adding margins on it

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

In order to maker distance between title and list items, I set an `<a>` with `margin: 8px 0;`. The weird thing is that the clickable area of the anchor expands just like I set paddings on the element however I did not. What is the situation?

```css
ul.footer-nav {
    margin: 0 12px;
}
ul.footer-nav > a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-nav">
    <a href="#help-and-information">HELP & INFORMATION</a>
    <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#track-order">Track Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delivery-and-returns">Delivery& Returns</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDITED----------

If I set both margin and padding on the element, the clickable area and the distance work correctly.

Comment: Shouldnt directly nest an `a` tag inside `ul`. Should only have `li` tags directly descended.

Comment: Can I use `a` as a direct child of UL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Comment: The requirement is not clear, can you please update the required output as image and specify what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` element is set to `display:block` which expands its clickable are, so it expands to the whole width. I'm guessing you did that because `a` is `display:inline` by default, and [vertical `margin` doesn't work for inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7611030/7586).

You can use `display: inline-block` instead, which will still display the `margin` setting. Here's an example. I've removed the `ul` entirely, and gave the `a` element background color, so we ca see what's happening:

```css
a {
    background-color:#fe5;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#help-and-information">HELP & INFORMATION</a>
```

Compare to the original with `display:block;`

```css
a {
    background-color:#fe5;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#help-and-information">HELP & INFORMATION</a>
```

Note that as the comments warn, you should not have an `a` element directly in a `ul` list - that isn't valid and may produce unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

One way, though it might be easiest to just move the link out of the ul.

```css
ul.footer-nav {
    margin: 0 12px;
}
ul.footer-nav > a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
ul.footer-nav li:first-child {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.footer-nav li:first-child a {
    text-decoration: none !important;       
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-nav">
    <li><a href="#help-and-information">HELP & INFORMATION</a></li>
    <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#track-order">Track Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delivery-and-returns">Delivery& Returns</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `ul` should only have the child elements as `li`.

If one wish to make headings, then there are other tags like `h1`, `h2`, etc.

So, you should modify your code as below:

```css
ul.footer-nav {
  margin: 0 12px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 > a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <a href="#help-and-information">HELP & INFORMATION</a>
</h3>
<ul class="footer-nav">
  <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
  <li><a href="#track-order">Track Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="#delivery-and-returns">Delivery& Returns</a></li>
</ul>
```