# Margin-top doesn't work when display is set to inline

Tags: html, css

I am working from a tutorial but wanted to try it out myself first. The problem is that while using hover over the link, the background color change touches the topmost of the navbar but doesn't touch the bottom of it.

`margin-top` doesn't work when the display is set to inline and I've tried padding and similar solutions. Here is my code:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.logo .text-primary {
    color: #85b84b;
}

a:hover{
    background: #85b84b;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

nav{
    background: #444;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

nav li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 1rem;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Its html code is:

```
<nav>
  <h1 class="logo">
     <span class="text-primary">
     <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Edge</span>Ledger
  </h1>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Who</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please replace "display:inline;" with "display:inline-block;" and add "vertical-align:middle;" in "nav li" selectore.    
Note - margin-top and margin-bottom will not work with display:inline.

Comment: You may want to check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611030/css-display-inline-block-does-not-accept-margin-top

Comment: Next time please add relevant html code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to make `align-items:center` it will make the things center.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.logo .text-primary {
    color: #85b84b;
}

a:hover{
    background: #85b84b;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

nav{
    background: #444;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

nav li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 1rem;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1 class="logo">
     <span class="text-primary">
     <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Edge</span>Ledger
  </h1>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Who</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top` and `margin-bottom` doesn't work for inline elements. Try changing the display to `inline-block` to provide margins or paddings vertically(top, bottom).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    ul#menu
    {
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: right;
        float: right;
    }

    ul#menu li
    {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
</style>


<nav>
    <h1 class="logo">
        <span >
            <i ></i> Edge</span>Ledger
    </h1>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Who</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Try this one it works for me. Use `float` property